# How to get private events from a soql query?

Tags: apex, soql, event

We ran into an issue where users at the top of the profile hierarchy can correctly retrieve all events of everyone below them, but they cannot retrieve each others events. We found out this is most likely due to their events being private (if no Related To is specified in their event). I added a random related object in the related to to one of these events that couldn't be seen by others in the top profile and it all the sudden was visible.

When we have without sharing in the controller, they can of course see all events. But for security reasons, we don't want without sharing set in the controller. Simply sharing their calendars amongst themselves in Salesforce did not work.

Is there a way to make sure to retrieve private events (that seem to ignore sharing rules) in an apex soql query?

Comment: Play with Sharing Settings to share records in between Roles of the same level in the hierarchy.

Comment: Do you happen to have any idea what the setting might be? We have not been able to find any sharing setting that lets you view private events of those at your hierarchy level.

Comment: Also, we have found that when the Related To is not set, it makes the event private and then throws out all sharing rules, which is an unfortunate problem. We haven't found any setting to stop that from happening, or to allow others to see your private events.